# Hello everyone, can someone help me, I want to read a text file in kivy textinput or label

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

imports:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
```

```
kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    text: newList
    TextInput:
        id: newList
    Button:
        text: 'click'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty('read.text')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        file = open('read.text', 'r')
        f = file.readlines()
        newList = []
        for line in f:
            newList.append(line.strip())
        print(newList)
        self.root.ids.your_textinput.text = (newList)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This message appears when I press run (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute).

Comment: have you tried setting a string instead of a list?
self.root.ids.your_textinput.text = '\n'.join(newList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are opening file named `read.text` which doesn't exist. Text files have extension `.txt`. As such file doesn't exist the file isn't opened and so nothing is added to the list `newList`. So all you have to do is change `.text` to `.txt`
Second thing is that you have given your textinput field the same id as the list which may cause error later. Also while doing `self.root.ids.your_textinput.text = (newList)` you are providing a list instead of providing text, which will also cause error. So your final code would be:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: text_field
    Button:
        text: 'click'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''

class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty('read.txt')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        file = open('read.txt', 'r')
        f = file.readlines()
        self.root.ids.text_field.text = (''.join(f))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: How do you know the correct name of the OP's file?

Comment: He's using 'read.text' in his code but text files have extension '.txt' not '.text'

Comment: It's perfectly possible for a file to have the extension `.text`. If the OP were trying to read a file that didn't exist, they would be getting a FileNotFoundError.

Comment: There were other errors in his code. I listed them all and after correcting them all, posted the final code too